# Set selection method is not working in gallery in android

Tags: android

I have done with Gallery in my project. It is working very fine, i was trying to use setSelection method of gallery so that at the start up i can define which item to be selected rather than always selecting first item.
I have tried to use setSelection(5) so that selection goes to 5th child but the gallery always select the first item. Is there any clue to integrated it perfectly.

Comment: You can paste some code, but I think that this automatic selection of the first element happens somewhere after you set it to the 5th.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this:

```
your_gallery_view.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    your_gallery_view.setSelection(5);
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that this solution works. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. We need to put the set selection method after setAdapter method. I was doi ng it before setting the updater. It is working fine. Thanks to all who tried to help me out.